# Compiled smart contract successfully but when I try to deploy it to goerli nothing happens

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, javascript, ethers.js, goerli

I'm working on a tutorial project and complied my smart contract successfully but when I try to deploy the contract I get 2 warnings from node and that's t, no error or any message or anything, the execution doesn't stop either, I waited for more than 20min and nothing is happening.[image]

Attaching Solidity file and Script,
[image][image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, this is a lazy response, I'm just sharing how I deploy contracts, 1. I set up my deployment script and then I just run like:

Command:

```
yarn hardhat deploy --tags deployWhitelist --network goerli
```

Script

```
import { developmentChains, networkConfig } from "../../helper-hardhat-config";
import verify from "../../utils/verify";
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

const deployWhitelist: DeployFunction = async function(hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  const { deployments, getNamedAccounts, network, ethers } = hre;
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  //i set the deployer wallet in hardat.config.ts
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts(); 
  const waitBlockConfirmations = 1

  const args = [10]

  console.log("----> Deploying whitelist <----");
  
  const whitelistContract = await deploy("whitelist", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations || 1
  });
  console.log("whitelist deployed at: ", whistelistContract.address);

};

export default deployWhitelist;
deployWhitelist.tags = ["all", "deployWhitelist", "main"];
```

I just did a rough refactor but if you use hardhat; you could just copy this code and run it locally and should work;  just change to your network of preference

source:
[hardhat deploy in a nutshell](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy/tree/master#hardhat-deploy-in-a-nutshell)